# Every closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$ has a point that minimizes the distance to a given point $p\in\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $p\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\|\cdot \|$ the Euclidian norm. Show that if $K\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a close set, then $$\exists a\in K: \forall x\in K, \|a-p\|\leq \|x-p\|.$$

Since $\|x-p\|\geq 0$, there is a $m\geq 0$ such that $$m=\inf_{x\in K}\|x-p\|.$$

Now, I have to show that there is a $a\in K$ such that $m=\|a-p\|$. My idea is to take a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset K$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\|x_n-p\|=m$. My problem is to show that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge or that $(x_n)$ has a subsequence that converge.

Comment: Hint: Find a compact set in the picture.

Comment: It's indeed what I tried to do, but I don't find a compact such that $(x_n)$ is in this compact.

Comment: Try intersecting $K$ with a suitable ball.

Comment: Hint: The orthogonal projection of $p$ on $K$.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ is a complete space and thus $K$ is complete.

Comment: **Mitos:** the completeness of $K$ doesn't help at this step since I need to have a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converge. **BolzWeir : ** How does it work ? thanks,

Comment: I finally found it: $\|x_n\|\leq \|x_{n}-p\|+\|p\|$ and thus $(x_n)$ is bounded. Therefore $(x_n)$ has a subsequence that converge and thus we get the result.

Comment: @idm Yup. $ $ $ $

Comment: @BolzWeir "I wonder how OP solved it." Using that every sequence in a compact set has a converging subsequence (as the OP explained), I guess.

Comment: You know, it's not nice to delete your own comment when someone is replying specifically to it. Like I just did.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding a convergent subsequence in was solved in comments. For completeness, here is a more general result which is not any harder to prove:

> If $f$ is a *proper* continuous function that is bounded from below, then $f$ attains its minimum on every nonempty  closed subset of its domain.

(A function is called proper if the preimage of every compact set is compact.)

Proof: suppose $E$ is closed; let $m=\inf_E f$. Since the set $E\cap f^{-1}([m,m+1])$ is compact and nonempty,   $f$ attains the value $m$.

---

Application to your problem: the function $f(x)=\|x-p\|$ is proper, continuous, and bounded below by $0$.